# Test Multiple HTML Templates To Make Sure They Return 200

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-testing

I have 100s of HTML Templates that I have to test and don't know how to test each individual one to make sure that they load properly.  I assume i would use a for loop through my project urls.py but when I do this i get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'URLResolver' object has no attribute 'name'

```
from django.test import SimpleTestCase, TestCase, Client
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
from django.urls import reverse, URLPattern
from django.conf import settings
import importlib
from foo.urls import urlpatterns

# Create your tests here.
class LoginTest(SimpleTestCase):
    def login_view_test(self):
        client = Client()
        for url in urlpatterns:
            response = client.get(reverse(url.name))
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
            print(str(reverse(url.name)) + " Status Code:" + str(response.status_code))
```

For some reason the code says that the URLResolver has no name attribute, I feel this error is it telling me I need to look in a different location for the name to reverse I just don't know where to look.

when removing the .name in the reverse tag, I got this error:

> <URLResolver <module 'account.urls' from '/home/company/company_project/account/urls.py'> (None:None) 'account/'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to give a `urlpattern` a name.

For example:

```
...
path('someurl/', generic.RedirectView.as_view(url='/anyurl/')),
...
```

results in a `URLPattern` without a name

```py
<URLPattern 'someurl/'>  # no name
```

In your case you could probably directly use the stored route:

```py
from django.test import SimpleTestCase, TestCase, Client
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
from django.urls import reverse, URLPattern
from django.conf import settings
import importlib
from foo.urls import urlpatterns

# Create your tests here.
class LoginTest(SimpleTestCase):
    def login_view_test(self):
        client = Client()
        for urlpattern in urlpatterns:
            if urlpattern.name is None:
                continue
            response = client.get(urlpattern.pattern._route))
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
            print(str(reverse(url.name)) + " Status Code:" + str(response.status_code))
```

Be aware that, that this does not work if you have pass some parameters, like primary keys.

Probably not yet the best solutions, since we are using a internal attribute, but it solves your issue :-)

Comment: Okay what if i want to skip the urlpatterns that dont have a name.

Comment: Add a `if urlpattern.name is None: continue` -> I updated the answer :-)

Comment: @Cade Did it help?

Comment: After running this I also ran into the problem of it not going through each included url file too so I took code from another Stack Overflow post and combined it with yours to get one that would do all of the urls even included ones, but yes your code did help!